# How to make linkedEditing and autoClosingTags work for Twig files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Settings `linkedEditing` and `autoClosingTags` works well with HTML and JSX:

```
{
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "html.autoClosingTags": true,
  "javascript.autoClosingTags": true,
  "typescript.autoClosingTags": true
}
```

Is there a way to make it work for Twig files too, without using the well known extensions [formulahendry.auto-close-tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-close-tag) and [formulahendry.auto-rename-tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag)?

I've tried, at least for `linkedEditing`, to set:

```
"[twig]": {
  "editor.linkedEditing": true
}
```

But it doesn't work too. Note that **I DO NOT want** to set the file association becase Twig has its own language/extension to do syntax highlight ad snippets:

```
"files.associations": {
  "*.twig": "html"
}
```

Comment: are you using any twig extensions?

Comment: @starball yes, "mblode.twig-language-2", why?

Comment: because you're probably looking for an extension which implements https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#LinkedEditingRangeProvider, and it doesn't look like that extension does https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Amblode%2Fvscode-twig-language-2%20LinkedEditingRangeProvider&type=code. You can write a feature request https://github.com/mblode/vscode-twig-language-2/issues/new. If you do, please link me to it.